# v-if inside v-for in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, conditional-statements

I am using the [Vue-google-maps](https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps) package to render a google map on my site with locations on it.

To display the locations with markers I am doing it like this:

```
<GmapMarker v-for="hotel in hotels" :key="hotel.id"
  :position="hotel._geoloc"
  :clickable="true"
  :draggable="false"
  @click="center=hotel._geoloc"
  @mouseover="show = true"
  @mouseleave="show = false" 
>
   <gmap-info-window v-if="show">
       <hotel-card :hotel="hotel" :session="session"/>
  </gmap-info-window>
</GmapMarker>
```

But for some reason(I am new to vue), it shows every info window and ignores the `v-if` statement. How can I fix this issue? In what way should I render it?

Comment: `v-if="show = true"` should probably be `v-if="show"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just like this.

```
hotels = []
axios.get("hotels").then( (data) => {
  hotels = data
})
```

just ignored that axios.get its just example that data came from backend. so as you can see hotels came from the request right or in the backend so to put a show property for that first thing is to know the condition what hotel should i show or hide.

```
hotels = []
axios.get("hotels").then( (data) => {
  if (data.slot === 0 )
    data.show = true
  else data.show = false

  hotels = data
})
```

just like that. i just check if the slot is equals to zero so i will not show that hotel. just for example. something like that

Comment: Well, when i did that, it does not show them, but when i hover a marker it shows them all. how can i make it to show only on that specific marker?

Comment: if in a specific data in a loop you can put show property in your hotels collection with a boolean data type. coz i you just declare anyware the show variable it will affect along the iteration. so much better to have a property show your hotels just like this..


hotels
`[{ id: 1, show: true },{ id: 2, show: false }]`
then
`v-if="hotel.show"`

Comment: I cant add this property to the hotels, sadly. is there any other way, please?

Comment: can you show to me how did you come up the hotels collection ?

Comment: what do you mean? i just send it from the back end.

Comment: i mean where did you get that hotels ? coz you can still add a show property for that. and also this one. how would you know for some specific data to be shown ?

Comment: As you can see, its in the v-for on the `GmapMarker` tag, at the top of the code. How can i add a show property to each hotel?

Comment: Just add a show property to each hotel object at your backend with false. And update your mouseover event to hotel.show = true. And maybe you can update the hotel.show to false on @mouseleave.